# Why am I getting NoClassDefFound org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing if I'm not using hamcrest at all in my Maven test?

Tags: java, maven, junit, dependencies, hamcrest

I have been into this for a while. The related questions in StackOverflow are about the absence of the `hamcrest-core` JAR in the classpath of the project, and the solutions are all related to its addition. What I am trying to do is de opposite: removing this dependency from the classpath.

Consider a Maven project with a single test case:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest {

    /**
     * Rigorous Test :-)
     */
    @Test
    public void shouldAnswerWithTrue() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Here the test `shouldAnswerWithTrue` invokes the method `assertTrue` in the class `Assert` from the dependency `junit` version 4.11 (declared in the POM). When I construct the corresponding call graph, the dependency `hamcrest-core` seems not to be used in this test case. `hamcrest-core` is a transitive dependency induced by the direct dependency `junit`. Therefore, I proceed to exclude it from the POM of my project as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However, when I execute `mvn package`, it triggers the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
```

I do not understand why Java is complaining about the interface `SelfDescribing` in a dependency that is not used at all in my test and in any of its methods calls. I have checked that no class from `hamcrest-core` is loaded from the `Assert` classes in JUnit.

So, Why I cannot exclude `hamcrest-core`? Why is this interface needed? Where is it called?

Comment: The problem is very simple. https://search.maven.org/artifact/junit/junit/4.11/jar if you take a look into the pom file of junit you see that there is a dependency defined to hamcrest which means it is needed. In the end it does not make sense to exclude a dependency which the project mantainer have decided to be used. So it's not astonishing that you will get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 2):

Because JUnit 4.11 actually depends on it at compile time: it [uses it in its exception hierarchy](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/c2e4d911fadfbd64444fb285342a8f1b72336169/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/AssumptionViolatedException.java#L15).  When the `AssumptionViolatedException` class is loaded, it will trigger a load of `SelfDescribing`.

Comment: I just executed `mvn compiler:testCompile -Dverbose=true` on the given example. However, no class from hamcrest is loaded according to the output. How to see the load of `SelfDescribing`?